# emacs shortcuts are not working

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, tramp

I've been trying to get tramp to work for Emacs and was having some problems so I upgraded my Aquamacs to the latest version. Ever since then I've had massive problems with shortcuts. C-x C-f no longer works as find-file and instead does next-buffer. If I try to remap it back to find-file in my .emacs file it still doesn't work. Though I have managed to map C-x C-o to find-file temporarily. Several other shortcuts are also broken inexplicably (with no sign of anything in my .emacs file). I've tried deleting my .emacs file completely, but it doesn't refresh back to the original shortcuts though I do know that it is reading that file because when I do make some changes ( such as C-x C-o mapped to find-file) it does reflect this. However, even when I delete the .emacs file it still keeps the color-face I chose in it.

It's also giving me problems with tramp still in that I get the following error even though I can ssh to the exact same remote host just fine when using a shell window inside of Aquamacs:

"ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: nodename nor servname provided, or not known. Process *tramp/ssh ssh* exited abnormally with code 255"

I've tried reverting to older versions of Aquamacs, deleting the application and reinstalling,  but nothing seems to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Mac OS X 10.6.8, Aquamacs 2.4 Emacs 23.50.1.

Comment: If you're not set on Aquamacs specifically, there's always http://emacsformacosx.com/